# How to select an element and its children in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with further divs contained in it.These divs internally contain table/div in them.
How can I select this parent div and its children in jquery? Parent div has the class "`AccordionTitle AccordionTitle-selected`"

I have tried following

`var klo=$(".AccordionTitle.AccordionTitle-selected").contents()`

and

```
var klo=$(".AccordionTitle.AccordionTitle-selected").children().clone()
```

but it is only selecting parent div and its children.Its not going deep to the root.I am using jquery 1.9.0

Thanks

Comment: [".children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree"](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `,` separator in order to select multiple queries. Something like this should do.

```
var klo=$(".AccordionTitle.AccordionTitle-selected, .AccordionTitle.AccordionTitle-selected > *")
```

This will select the element itself as well as elements *right beneath* the element itself in the DOM tree.

If you're looking for a solution to find child elements **and** their child elements too, something like this will do.

```
var klo=$(".AccordionTitle.AccordionTitle-selected, .AccordionTitle.AccordionTitle-selected *")
```

The principle is the same, only now you've omitted the `>` operator which will only allow children right below the original node.

Comment: Hi Mathias Lykkegaard Lorenzen, I tried your second option of selecting all child elements with * but its not going to root level.Any other thing which we can try?

Comment: Thanks Mathias Lykkegaard Lorenzen!! I worked.I was doing typo mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Try [.addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/)

```
var klo=$(".AccordionTitle.AccordionTitle-selected").children().addBack()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`find('*')`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to select all descendant elements, then [`addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) to add the parent back into the selection. I've included `clone` at the end too, if the clone is what you want in the variable.

```
var klo=$(".AccordionTitle.AccordionTitle-selected").find('*').addBack().clone();
```

Answer (score 3):

use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)  instead of `children()`

`children():`retrieves only the single descendant child.

`find("*"):`It will retrieve all the descendant elements.

`*:`Universal Selector.

```
var klo=$(".AccordionTitle.AccordionTitle-selected").find('*');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var klo = $(".your.classes, .your.classes div");
```